# PHP. Find the lowest day among randomly generated dates in the array

Tags: php, arrays, date, max, min

I just started learning PHP. The last 3 days I suffer on a task. Google refuses to help. The problem follows.

There is a task - to find the lowest day among randomly generated dates in an array $date. That's what I did:

```
// Create two variables of type timestamp with the minimum and maximum value dates

    $Min = strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
    $Max = strtotime('3000-01-01 00:00:00');

// Create an array of 5 random dates, using a random number generator

    for ($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {$date[$i] = rand($min, $max);}

// Check, like all good

    var_dump($date);

// Now I want to select the day of the accident the smallest output of dates. Or, for example, the largest month. I enter the command

    $Y = min(date('d', $date[$i]));

    var_dump($y);
```

But the browser then swears, produces errors:

> (!) Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in
>
> (!) Warning: min (): When only one parameter is given, it must be an
>   array in

// I have tried to use the mark - @, but it does not solve the problem, but only hide the error.

I understand that mistakes mean, supposedly wrong index, and that $ Y - is not an array. Tried $ Y expressed in terms of an array, but was still 5 errors

// I have tried to write this line in such a way:

```
$Y = min(date('d', $date[0]), date('d', $date[1]), date('d', $date[2]), date('d', $date[3]), date('d', $date[4]));
```

!!! **BINGO** !!! Everything worked !!! **But** what if I will have 25,000 elements in the array $date, how long I'm going to write this line?

Dear programmers, please help. How to write the last line rationally, briefly and clearly, to perform tasks without error conditions? What is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: hint: investigate further with `var_dump`

Comment: Hint: you are using an *array* of ints, and trying to get its *min*imum (but you are not passing an array of ints to min(), you are passing an int). Hint2: even without that option, there must be a way of *loop*ing over an array and comparing the current element to something.

Comment: `date` returns a string, `min` expects an array. `min(date(...))` is **NEVER** going to work. and doing `min()` on a single value is pointless anyways. a single value is always its minimum AND maximum simultaneously. `min(array(date(), date(), date(), ...)))` would work, however.

Comment: (Of course, in a real-world scenario, you would load the dates into a database (because you're probably doing something else with them anyway), sort it, and get the first one.)

Comment: You're defining $Min and $Max with the first letter as a capital (uncommon). Those variables are not used in your code, but you've similar variables $min and $max which are not set.

Answer (score 0):

The robust solution is by using a for loop to compare every element, of perhaps a foreach loop.

```
$min = date('d', $date[0]);
foreach($date as $d){
    $min = min(date('d', $d), $min);
}
```

A for loop would do the same trick, but you would have to refer to the index number. But save yourself the trouble unless you also want to know what element of the array it is.

Answer (score 0):

I know it seems strange but you could actually use what little php(7) provides:

```
// 10 random ints
$randoms = array_map(function(){ 
    return rand(); 
},range(0,10));

// 10 random dates
$dates = array_map(function($rand_int){ 
    // there is probably a easier way to do that
    return (new DateTimeImmutable())->setTimeStamp($rand_int); 
},$randoms);

// apply min and extract Day or whatever you like.
var_dump( min($dates)->format('Y-m-d - l') );

// result:
// string(21) "1974-11-23 - Saturday"
```

The following little note is kind of important:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

> As of PHP 5.2.2, DateTime objects can be compared using comparison operators.

Which `min` should do under-the-hood.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it working, just some small mistakes.

- unused variables ($Min and $Max)
- undefined variables ($date, $min and $max)
- undefined key ($date[$i])
- incorrect usage of min()

In php it's common to write your variables names lowercase, same for function names.

```
// define all variables needed
$dates = array();
$min = strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
$max = strtotime('3000-01-01 00:00:00');

for ($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $dates[$i] = rand($min, $max);
}

// lookup the lowest date int and convert it to a date string
$accident = date('d', min($dates));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just sort the Timestamps in order of lowest to highest with `natsort`, and then select the first element from the sorted array.

```
natsort($dates);
$lowest = $dates[0];
```

That way you should have the first lowest possible value out of your Timestamps.

Here's the manual page on [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) for more information on the function

Answer (score 0):

my friend.

before using functions you should read documentation about them.

so you cannot use strtotime like that:

```
strtotime('3000-01-01 00:00:00');
```

it will return you "false" and not integer. be carefull with this.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

and one more:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

Also you should know that in  php The variable name is case-sensitive. so in your example

```
 $Min = strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
    $Max = strtotime('3000-01-01 00:00:00');

// Create an array of 5 random dates, using a random number generator

    for ($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {$date[$i] = rand($min, $max);}
```

variables $min and $Min is differend.

so variable $min is undefined.

Now you can look at my simple solution:

```
<?php
// Create two variables of type timestamp with the minimum and maximum value dates

$Min = strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
var_dump('Min = '. $Min);
$Max = strtotime('2030-01-01 00:00:00');
var_dump('Max = '. $Max);


// Create an array of 5 random dates, using a random number generator

for ($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {$date[$i] = rand($Min, $Max);}

// Check, like all good

var_dump($date);

// Now I want to select the day of the accident the smallest output of dates. Or, for example, the largest month. I enter the command

$array = [];
foreach($date as $value)
{
    $array[date('Y-m-d', $value)] = date('d', $value);
}
var_dump($array);


$Y = min($array);

var_dump($Y);
```